# How can I take the element that appear with toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

Suppose to have a html page. In this html page there is a button and when I click on the button it appear a toogle where there are a button:

(In the toggle code)

```
<button id="new">New</button>
```

I need to remove this button so I use jquery:

```
$('#new').remove();
```

But the button doesn't remove. I think because theare is a problem of loading with the js and the toggle. Anyone can help me?

Comment: what error are you having?

Comment: F12 browser ->  look at console

Comment: Make sure you've included jQuery properly and are running your code in a document.ready handler

Comment: Do you want to remove button after page get loaded or on any other event listener.

Comment: it doesn't me an error button but It look like when I think I must use some method that allows to be secure that the button is loaded before to call function

Comment: See example when you click on button it will go away : https://plnkr.co/edit/xa1ylenJ0XDC7DkTbW60?p=preview

Comment: This can be happen if you are using the a third party library to render toggle button and that library appends additional markup to build that button. So in that case removing the base button may not remove the additional markup. Check with **browser developer tools**.

Answer (score 0):

Please put button remove code in `document.ready` as below. Because of it your code will be executed after page loaded get completed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#new').remove();
});
```